# How can I resolve java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory?

Tags: java

I'm trying to run my project outside of my IDE and I'm getting this java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

It works fine inside the IDE but when trying to run it from a batch file it's loading the application panel and throwing this error.

I have included all of the libraries in the batch file, all of them are present and they are the same libraries that are used inside of the IDE.

```
java -cp bin;deps/InetAddressLocator.jar;deps/lombok.jar;deps/commons-collections4-4.0.jar;deps/mina-core-1.1.7.jar;deps/mysql.jar;deps/slf4j-api-1.6.1;deps/slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar; game.engine.GameEngine true 0 0
pause
```

How can I fix this?

```
[02/06/2014 12:42:52 AM]: Exception in thread "main" 
[02/06/2014 12:42:52 AM]: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
[02/06/2014 12:42:52 AM]:   at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.<init>(NamePreservingRunnable.java:32)
[02/06/2014 12:42:52 AM]:   at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketAcceptor.startupWorker(SocketAcceptor.java:165)
[02/06/2014 12:42:52 AM]:   at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.SocketAcceptor.bind(SocketAcceptor.java:141)
[02/06/2014 12:42:52 AM]:   at game.engine.GameEngine.main(GameEngine.java:125)
[02/06/2014 12:42:52 AM]: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
[02/06/2014 12:42:52 AM]:   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
[02/06/2014 12:42:52 AM]:   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
[02/06/2014 12:42:52 AM]:   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[02/06/2014 12:42:52 AM]:   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
[02/06/2014 12:42:52 AM]:   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[02/06/2014 12:42:52 AM]:   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[02/06/2014 12:42:52 AM]:   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[02/06/2014 12:42:52 AM]:   ... 4 more
```

Comment: Add the slf4j JAR to the CLASSPATH.  That's what that exception means.  It's Java 101.

Comment: what is you current directory, because deps/ is a relative path. it would only work if you are running the command from the parent directory of deps

Comment: It is in the classpath? deps/slf4j-api-1.6.1;deps/slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `java -cp bin;deps/InetAddressLocator.jar;deps/lombok.jar;deps/commons-collections4-4.0.jar;deps/mina-core-1.1.7.jar;deps/mysql.jar;deps/slf4j-api-1.6.1;deps/slf4j-simple-1.6.1.jar; game.engine.GameEngine true 0 0`

slf4j-api-1.6.1 is mising the ".jar" at the end. It should read as "slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar"

Comment: deps/slf4j-api-1.6.1;

It's there

Comment: does it includes ".jar" at the end?

Comment: Oh I've just realised I missed the extension! Thanks for pointing that out. *facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

I think, better to work with [Manifest Files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html).